# Removing Kubuntu and Installing Windows instead

Tags: windows-10, iso-image, windows-installation

A friend gave me his Asus netbook to use for school and has Kubuntu 14.10 installed on it.

I would like to remove Kubuntu and install Windows instead. I have the Windows .iso file but have not been able to mount it or install Windows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not the first person to want to install Windows from an ISO file; how to do it is all over the Internet, so it would kind of be a waste for people to write a new tutorial just for you.  You just need to look.  If you Google "install Windows from iso file", you will get endless tutorials covering every possible configuration.  For example: https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-clean-install-windows-10-from-iso-file-without-usbdvd/ was near the top of the list.

Comment: BTW, Kubuntu will be wiped when you install Windows, so you don't need to do it as an extra step.

Comment: I am unable to mount the .iso file on Kubuntu 14.10. which is the main issue. That link shows the computer already running windows. I am running Kubuntu 14.10 and am unable to mount the file and access the .exe

Answer (score 0):

you need a flash disk and a software to make flash disk bootable.

see [install-winusb-in-ubuntu-14-04](https://itsfoss.com/install-winusb-in-ubuntu-14-04/)

**EDIT:**

you can also try [WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB) for Ubuntu 17.10 or above:

to install WoeUSB:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install woeusb
```

Comment: This tutorial at this link does not work. I cannot install winusb after following it exactly

Comment: try [WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB)

Answer (score 0):

1. Write Windows ISO to a USB Stick. Use [OpenSuse Imagewriter](https://software.opensuse.org/package/imagewriter), build-in Kubuntu ISO writer or similar.
2. Boot from that USB stick.
3. Make Windows 10 installation.

Comment: opsuse imagewriter cannot install the Windows 10 iso that I have. It says that i have to use a different image writer in order to write that iso